# What am I doing wrong in calculating cidr IP range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a function that will output some address information on a CIDR formatted IP (output underneath code):

```
create function dbo.ConvertIpToInt (@Ip as varchar(15))
    returns bigint
    as
    begin
        return (convert(bigint, parsename(@Ip, 1)) +
                convert(bigint, parsename(@Ip, 2)) * 256 +
                convert(bigint, parsename(@Ip, 3)) * 256 * 256 +
                convert(bigint, parsename(@Ip, 4)) * 256 * 256 * 256)
    end
go


create function dbo.ConvertIntToIp (@Int bigint) 
    returns varchar(15)
    as 
    begin
        declare
             @IpHex     varchar(8)
            ,@IpDotted  varchar(15)

        select
             @IpHex = substring(convert(varchar(30), master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(@Int)), 11, 8)

        select
            @IpDotted = convert(varchar(3), convert(int, (convert(varbinary, substring(@IpHex, 1, 2), 2)))) + '.' +
                        convert(varchar(3), convert(int, (convert(varbinary, substring(@IpHex, 3, 2), 2)))) + '.' +
                        convert(varchar(3), convert(int, (convert(varbinary, substring(@IpHex, 5, 2), 2)))) + '.' +
                        convert(varchar(3), convert(int, (convert(varbinary, substring(@IpHex, 7, 2), 2))))
        return @IpDotted
    end
go


create function dbo.GetCidrIpRange (@CidrIp varchar(15))
    returns @result table
    (
        CidrIp      varchar(15) not null,
        Mask        int not null,
        LowRange    varchar(15) not null,
        LowIp       varchar(15) not null,
        HighRange   varchar(15) not null,
        HighIp      varchar(15) not null,
        AddressQty  bigint not null
    )
    as
    begin
        declare @Base       bigint  = cast(4294967295 as bigint)
        declare @Mask       int     = cast(substring(@CidrIp, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)
        declare @Power      bigint  = Power(2.0, 32.0 - @Mask) - 1
        declare @LowRange   bigint  = dbo.ConvertIpToInt(left(@CidrIp, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIp) - 1)) & (@Base ^ @Power)
        declare @HighRange  bigint  = @LowRange + @Power

        insert @result
        select
              CidrIp     = @CidrIp
            , Mask       = @Mask
            , LowRange   = @LowRange
            , LowIp      = dbo.ConvertIntToIp(@LowRange)
            , HighRange  = @HighRange
            , HighIp      = dbo.ConvertIntToIp(@HighRange)
            , AddressQty = convert(bigint, power(2.0, (32.0 - @Mask)))
        return
    end
go

select * from dbo.GetCidrIpRange('195.65.254.11/2');
```

This outputs the following:

```
CidrIp           Mask   LowRange    LowIp      HighRange   HighIp           AddressQty
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
195.65.254.11/2  2      3221225472  192.0.0.0  4294967295  255.255.255.255  1073741824
```

I have been browsing SO and Google for some hours now, and I am quite convinced that `ConvertIpToInt` and `ConvertIntToIp` are correct.

However, I was expecting the following output:

```
CidrIp           Mask   LowRange    LowIp         HighRange   HighIp          AddressQty
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
195.65.254.11/2  2      3275881985  195.65.254.1  3275882238  195.65.254.254  254
```

Can someone please point me out where the mistake in my code is? I've been staring myself blind and I don't see it (or I am misunderstanding how to do this).

Comment: Not your current problem, I believe, but your input data type seems too small - e.g. `172.172.172.172/24` is too big to fit into a `varchar(15)`.

Comment: This calculator suggests your functions are working correctly: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr  Why do you think your output is incorrect?  If you put `195.65.254.11/24` into that calculator you get very similar results to your expected output, that include both address `0` and `255` which bumps the `AddressQty` to `256`, but those are the only differences.

Comment: I think it is incorrect because logically, the IP range doesn't make any sense, as confirmed here: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=195.65.254.11&mask1=24&mask2=

Comment: As an aside, the undocumented `master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr` has been unnecessary for quite a while. `CONVERT` can turn `BINARY` into hex strings and vice versa by passing an appropriate style parameter. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928) under "binary styles". (Converting other data to hex strings requires turning it into `BINARY` first, of course.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good point. But I think O.P. might already know since `CONVERT` with a "style" of `2` is used in the very next `SELECT` statement in that function. Not sure why that same usage wasn't applied, but this example should illustrate that it does work in both directions: `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(30), '0x3032', 1) AS [StringToBinary], CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), 0x3032, 1) AS [BinaryToString];`. HOWEVER, it would be better / more efficient to keep it as a purely math operation, and I have updated my answer to show how that can be done :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to both http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr and http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=195.65.254.11&mask1=2&mask2=, your calculations are correct. The only disagreement between those two sites is that the **jodies.de/ipcalc** page removes the lowest and highest (broadcast) IP addresses from the range.

I tested with both `195.65.254.11/2` and `195.65.254.11/24`. In order to get your code working, I needed to change the input parameter specification on `dbo.GetCidrIpRang` to be `VARCHAR(20)` (as mentioned by @Damien_The_Unbeliever in a [comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090779/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-calculating-cidr-ip-range/42094644#comment71351808_42090779)).

Two notes regarding performance:

1. For the `ConvertIpToInt` and `ConvertIntToIp` Scalar UDFs you might be better off using the **INET_AddressToNumber** and **INET_NumberToAddress** functions, respectively, that are included in the Free version of the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) SQLCLR library (which I wrote, but hey, Free :). The reason for this recommendation is that unlike T-SQL UDFs, *deterministic* SQLCLR UDFs (and these two are) do not prevent parallel plans.
2. If you don't want to go the SQLCLR route, then you should, at the very least, keep the `ConvertIntToIp` function as purely mathematical. There is no reason to do all of those conversions and substrings.

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IPNumberToAddress(@IPNumber BIGINT)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(15)
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
   AS
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @Oct1 BIGINT,
              @Oct2 INT,
              @Oct3 INT;

       SET @Oct1 = @IPNumber / (256 * 256 * 256);
       SET @IPNumber -= (@Oct1 * (256 * 256 * 256));

       SET @Oct2 = @IPNumber / (256 * 256);
       SET @IPNumber -= (@Oct2 * (256 * 256));

       SET @Oct3 = @IPNumber / 256;
       SET @IPNumber -= (@Oct3 * 256);

       RETURN CONCAT(@Oct1, '.', @Oct2, '.', @Oct3, '.', @IPNumber);
   END;
   GO
   ```

   And then:

   ```sql
   SELECT dbo.IPNumberToAddress(3275881995);
   -- 195.65.254.11
   ```
3. For the `GetCidrIpRange` TVF, you would be better off converting that to be an Inline TVF. You can accomplish the multi-step calculations via CTEs in the following manner (you will just need to clean it up a little / finish it):

   ```sql
   WITH cte1 AS
   (
       SELECT 2 AS [Mask] -- replace with real formula
   ), cte2 AS
   (
       SELECT 999 AS [Base], -- replace with real formula
              POWER(2.0, 32.0 - cte1.[Mask]) - 1 AS [Power],
           cte1.[Mask]
       FROM   cte1
   ), cte3 AS
   (
       SELECT SQL#.INET_AddressToNumber(left(@CidrIp, PATINDEX('%/%' , @CidrIp) - 1))
           & (cte2.[Base] ^ cte2.[Power]) AS [LowRange],
           cte2.[Power],
           cte2.[Mask]
       FROM   cte2
   )
   SELECT @CidrIp AS [CidrIp],
           cte3.[Mask],
           cte3.[LowRange],
           SQL#.INET_NumberToAddress(cte3.[LowRange]) AS [LowIp],
           (cte3.[LowRange] + cte3.[Power]) AS [HighRange],
           SQL#.INET_NumberToAddress(cte3.[LowRange] + cte3.[Power]) AS [HighIp],
           CONVERT(BIGINT, POWER(2.0, (32.0 - cte3.[Mask]))) AS [AddressQty]
   FROM   cte3 c;
   ```